# Socket.IO, SSL, nginx, directory path

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, socket.io

So I use a *standalone* version of socket.io (server) -> I don't declare any "http server"
It looks pretty much like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){});
io.listen(3001);
```

The problem: my website in production environment is fully **HTTPS**. 
When I tried to connect to it ( `io.connect("https://www.mysite.com:3001")` ) I got ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (tested in Chrome browser).

When I turned off the server, I got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
So I came to a conclusion that Node.JS cannot handle the HTTPS/SSL connection.

My development environment is HTTP-based, so I have no problem there - it works like a charm.

So, then I decided to try proxy-passing the HTTPS to HTTP connection, using nginx.

AFAIK, here I have only couple of options in order to distinguish between Node.JS connection and main app connection:

a) Subdomain (~ node.mysite.com)

b) Directory (~ mysite.com/node)

I chose the latter option, because it felt much easier to implement.

So I added the following inside of a main "server" config (before the main app):

```
location /node {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

And then I tried connecting: `io.connect("https://www.mysite.com/node")`, but no matter what I get **404 (Not Found)**. 
I even tried this: `io.connect("https://www.mysite.com", {path : /node/})` (w and w/o slashes) and tried renaming *path* to *resource* and many more.

But no avail.

When I visit this page in the browser (and when the server is up and running) - I see a white page.

I'm I doing something terribly wrong? Can this be fixed?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with a subdomain. Because I wanted to delegate the connection handling to Nginx instead of doing it with the Node.JS itself. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also used the socket.IO connection on SSL like this .. it work fine to me ...i am using Express Engine

```
 var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')
 };

 var app = require('./app');
 var server = require('https').createServer(options, app),
 io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
 server.listen(port);
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 });
```

and on Client side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:2406');
// on connection to server, ask for user's name with an anonymous callback
socket.on('connect', function(){});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
Is is somehow possible to avoid "creating an http server"?

Comment: Even if you don't explicitly create the http server the socket io server will create one under the hood. However, I believe you can pass the options variable here (with key and cert chain) as the second argument to io.listen(). Its worth knowing though that socket.io will still create an http server behind the scenes so you might as well declare it yourself as shown here and in the socket.io docs.